# Weird account problems, using SQL Server from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, account

I have installed SQL Server Express on a remote server with Windows authentication.
I connect to this server via PowerShell from a client system via `import-pssession`.

Then I use `Invoke-sqlcmd` to do SQL stuff. This works fine. I connect to `Servername\SQLExpress`.

On the server side, I have installed SQL Server Management Studio to support my scripting.

I log into SQL Server with the same credentials (connecting to `Servername\SQLExpress`) as I use remotely.

When I use my database (same name, same tables) I have different content. On the PowerShell site I have 12 data sentences, on the MS I have one (different). I don't understand the world.

When I try to `Invoke-sqlcmd` via Powershell from the server, I get

> Cannot open database, login failed

What have I done wrong?

Thanks for every help

Comment: *I have 12 data sentences* - please explain what you mean by "data sentences" - that's not a commonly used and generally understood term.....

Comment: It's a literal translation of the German word "Datensatz", which means "record". I'm assuming the OP is German.

Comment: Please post how you create a PSsession you later use in import-pssession.

Comment: if(!(Get-PSSession | Where-Object{$_.ComputerName -eq $ini.SQLServer} ))
  
{   $CompName = $ini.SQLServer        
$script:pssess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $CompName -Credential $script:Cred   }

else {  $script:pssess = Get-PSSession  }

Comment: Sorry about the "sentences", it's naturally records.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question directly, instead of putting additional code and clarifications into the comment section.

Comment: And while you're at it, please go over your entire text again and give more details on each step, because it's still extremely hard to follow what you are doing. Ideally post the smallest-possible code sample that fails in the way you describe ([mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
Inadvertently I created two tables. One in my User-DB, one within the masterdb, where I never looked.
So I worked with two different tables from Powershell and from SQL Server Management Studio.
Thanks for your help.